# VNC without pass from external internet

Tags: ssh, vnc

### Problem

I want to use raspberryPi's Chrome from my Mac in order to watch some videos.
In order to do that, I am trying to make VNC connection.

### Condition

- raspberry pi and my Mac uses different network.
- I prefer to control raspberry pi by command, totally.
- The router of raspberryPi Port 5901 for VNC has been already opened.
- Public key authentication is the way to access.
- Password auth is restricted.

Comment: "I want to use raspberryPi's Chrome from my Mac" doesn't sound like a problem to me, more like a wish.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/757974) may help.

Answer (score 1):

using `ssh -XY 192.168.3.14` where `192.168.3.14` is the ip address of your raspberry pi to `ssh` into your raspberry pi and then run:

`pi@pimoroni:~ $ echo $DISPLAY`

you should the see:

`localhost:10.0`

If you see the `localhost:10.0` or similar line then you can just run `chromium-browser` and the browser will open on the computer you used to `ssh` into the pi.

Depending on how ssh is configured you can use either `-X` or `-Y` flag.

-X      Enables X11 forwarding.

-Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding

If it does not work `ssh -vvv` will give verbose output which will hopefully help you solve any issues.

Comment: Thanks for kind answer, but it seems very slow, is there any way to help that?

Comment: @IsseiMorita Try `ssh -XYC` to enable compression.

Comment: @jake Thank you, it became pretty faster, but could you tell me whatever I can do to make faster?

Comment: I want to watch video through raspberry pi.

Comment: @IsseiMorita Why do you to do want that?  Maybe you should consider using VPN or `sshuttle` instead.

Comment: Because I need to change my IP address and VPN doesn't work for me maybe since I use Public Auth instead of Password.